# How to show videoView in alert dialog android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I try with different code but video not shown in alert dialog box. I want to shown video in Alert dialog box but in my case only alert dialog box show but video view not shown.

**Here Code**

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppTheme);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
LinearLayout preview1 = (LinearLayout)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.preview);
VideoView videoView1 = new VideoView(getApplicationContext());
videoView1.setVideoURI(uri);
videoView1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
videoView1.start();
preview1.addView(videoView1);
Alert alert = dialogBuilder.create();
Window window;
window = alert.getWindow();
window.setLayout(getMaxWidth(), 400);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = window.getAttributes();
lp.token = mInputView.getWindowToken();
lp.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG;
window.setAttributes(lp);
lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
lp.x = 0;
lp.y = 600; 
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
alert.show();
```

**Popup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Make your custom activity like you want and use it as alert dialog.

Comment: @parikdhakan I already make popup.xml and its call in alert dialog but its not work. Yes, when add videoview replace with imageview its work perfectly.
only for video view not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
videoView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1));
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }
            });
```

It looks like your video view is not stretched to video's size. Try to add videoview's height as 1px and then after loading video in it - set to match_parent (width) and wrap_content (for height)

Answer (score 0):

> Java

```
    MediaController mc;
    boolean bVideoIsBeingTouched = false;
    public void showNewNameDialog(final String title) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = Fragment1.in;
        final View alertLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);
        final VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) 
    alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.videoview);
        final   Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        try {

           mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
                            mc = new MediaController(Fragment1.in.getContext());
                            mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
                            mc.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
                            ((ViewGroup) mc.getParent()).removeView(mc);
                            ((FrameLayout) alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.videoViewWrapper)).addView(mc);
                            mc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                    mVideoView.start();

                }
            });
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://video.mp4");
            mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            mVideoView.start();
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Fragment1.in.getContext(), R.style.myFullscreenAlertDialogStyle);
            ///alert.setTitle(title);
            alert.setIcon(R.mipmap.logo);
            //alert.setMessage(datos);
            // this is set the view from XML inside AlertDialog
            alert.setView(alertLayout);
            // disallow cancel of AlertDialog on click of back button and outside touch
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setNegativeButton("X  Salir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            final AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
            dialog.show();
            mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Toast.makeText(inflater.getContext(), "Gracias...!!!\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Mostrar un brindis cuando se completa un video
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    Toast.makeText(inflater.getContext(), "¡Ocurrió un error al reproducir video ...!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Mostrar un brindis cuando se produce un error mientras se reproduce un video
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            mVideoView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (!bVideoIsBeingTouched) {
                        bVideoIsBeingTouched = true;
                        if (mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
                            try{
                                mVideoView.pause();
                                mc.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                mc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                Toast.makeText(inflater.getContext(), "¡Ocurrió un error al reproducir video ...!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Mostrar un brindis cuando se produce un error mientras se reproduce un video
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }

                        } else {
                            try {
                                mVideoView.start();
                                mc.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                mc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }catch (Exception e){
                                Toast.makeText(inflater.getContext(), "¡Ocurrió un error al reproducir video ...!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Mostrar un brindis cuando se produce un error mientras se reproduce un video
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }

                        }
                        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                bVideoIsBeingTouched = false;
                            }
                        }, 100);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(inflater.getContext(), "¡Ocurrió un error al reproducir video ...!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Mostrar un brindis cuando se produce un error mientras se reproduce un video
        }

    }
```

> dialog_signin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoViewWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#808080"></FrameLayout>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoview"
        android:layout_width="640dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"></VideoView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

   
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                final AlertDialog dialogVideo = builder.create();
                View dialogView = 
    `enter code here`LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.videopopup_lay,null);
                dialogVideo.setView(dialogView);
                dialogVideo.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                dialogVideo.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

                        VideoView videoView =(VideoView)dialogVideo.findViewById(R.id.Video_player2);
                        videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://"+ context.getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.vedio);
                        MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(getContext());
                        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                        videoView.start();
                    }
                });dialogVideo.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try (StorageRef with Firebase)

```
        VideoView video;
        final ViewGroup nullParent = null;
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.video_view, nullParent);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(view.getContext());
        video = view.findViewById(R.id.view_videoView);

        storageRef.child("casa"+"/" + id + "/video.mp4")
                .getDownloadUrl()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        video.setVideoURI(uri);
                        video.setMediaController(mediaController);
                        mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
                        video.start();
                    }
                });

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext())
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

try out this code

```
image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// custom dialog
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.introvid);
dialog.show();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
final VideoView videoview = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.introvideo);
videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
videoview.start();
}
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18998686/6619234 if u know this than give link in comment.dont copy and paste answer...